# 1180:Call to a possibly undefined method Punch

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm trying to call the punch function from my player class inside another class but for some reason it gives me this error:

```
1180: Call to a possibly undefined method Punch.
```

I'm not sure why it gives me this error. I even made the functions public.

This is the class where i am calling it from:

```
package 
{
    public class Player extends MovieClip
    {
        public function Player()
        {
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,KeyDown);
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,KeyPressed);
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,Update);
        }


        function KeyPressed(event:KeyboardEvent):void
        {
            //If on floor
            if (CanJump)
            {
                //If A key is down
                if (event.keyCode == 65)
                {
                    //Punch
                    Punch(true);
                }
            }
        }


        function Update(event:Event)
        {
            //Do stuff
        }

    }
}
```

and this is what I am trying to call:

```
package 
{

    public class ComboSequence extends ComboHandler
    {

        public function ComboSequence(clipName:String, par:BaseObject, _oList:ObjectList)
        {
            // constructor code
            super(clipName, par, _oList);

        }

        public function Punch(PunchKey:Boolean)
        {
            if (currentAttack != null)
            {
                if (Recovery <= 0 && FollowUpTime > 0)
                {
                    currentAttack = currentAttack.GetNextAttack(PunchKey);

                    if (currentAttack != null)
                    {
                        SetAnimation(currentAttack.animName);
                        Recovery = currentAttack.Recovery;
                        FollowUpTime = currentAttack.Recovery + 25;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (FollowUpTime > 0)
            {
                FollowUpTime--;
            }
            else
            {
                currentAttack = null;
            }

            if (Recovery > 0)
            {
                Recovery--;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call `Punch()` on its own inside the player class, ActionScript is looking for a `Player.Punch()` method. Your method is on the `ComboSequence` class. You're probably trying to do something like this:

```
var comboSequence:ComboSequence = new ComboSequence();
comboSequence.Punch()
```

Keep in mind that while this code will run, it probably won't do what you want it to do. I guess you want to keep an instance of `ComboSequence` in your player object. If that doesn't make sense to you, it would be a good idea to do some background reading on ActionScript and object-oriented programming in general.

Comment: Thanks but i get new error i added this
`public var comboSequence:ComboSequence = new ComboSequence(clipName:String, par:BaseObject, _oList:ObjectList);`
as it needed three arguements but now i get errors saying expecting rightparen before colon. What on earth is a rightparen

Comment: Sounds like you're having trouble with the fundamentals of the language. I highly recommend you walk through a beginner ActionScript tutorial. If this is your first project, try something simpler to begin with and come to this when you're more confident.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import **ComboSequence** into the **Player** class and call **Punch** though that like
**ComboSequence.Punch**.  **andypaxo** is right in his post, you'd need to instantiate it somewhere within the **Player** class.

One note about your code, though, you should not name functions with a capital letter.  Class names typically start with a capital letter, but not the methods within.

```
package 
{
    import ComboSequence; //you may need the package path if its in a package, something like com.classes.ComboSequence, where com.classes is the folder that ComboSequence is saved.

    public class Player extends MovieClip
    {
        public function Player()
        {
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,KeyDown);
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,KeyPressed);
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,Update);
        }


        function KeyPressed(event:KeyboardEvent):void
        {
            //If on floor
            if (CanJump)
            {
                //If A key is down
                if (event.keyCode == 65)
                {
                    //Punch
                    ComboSequence.Punch(true);
                }
            }
        }


        function Update(event:Event)
        {
            //Do stuff
        }

    }
}
```

also, regarding your "missing rightParen" error, **rightParen** means **right parenthesis**, or **)**, **leftParen** would be **(**.  That error means you are missing a **)** somewhere.  Often times it can mean you added an extra one somewhere, thus closing a section of parenthesis you didn't mean to close, which would leave one unpaired parenthesis somewhere.

Comment: Thanks but now i get error Called to a possibly undefined method Punch through a reference with Static type class

Comment: I know this is a frustrating thing, but it sounds like you need to learn a bit more about classes and scope.  There's too many possible reasons for things to go wrong to help you line by line, step by step here. Read up on static classes vs instantiated classes.

Comment: Thanks i did not know there were different class types seems like i got alot of learning to do, i have made flash games before and thought i was more confident but seems like there are still more for me to learn

Comment: Try not to be discouraged.  There's always more to learn, even when you think you've learned it all!  I can't at the moment, but when I have a minute I'll look through my references for a good tutorial on classes in as3.  A Google search on it should get you started.